# Execute INSERT statements present in a file

Tags: mysql, insert, load

I have a file with many `INSERT` statements. How do I execute them without having to manually copy  them and paste them for execution. It is quite tough to do it that way, as the file is about `60 MB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import a file for mysql to run both from the `mysql` executable (command prompt) and the client itself.  I think the former is easier:

```
mysql < file-to-import.sql
```

(you may need username/password, etc.)

Comment: What does your `INSERT` file look like...?

Comment: I resolved the earlier issue @Explosion Pills. Just want to know if i have to enter the whole path i am doing this in cmd
mysql > C:\users\mysql files\data.sql; 

Is it corrent

Comment: I think you do have to enter the whole path, but you want `<` not `>`

Answer (score 0):

Create your file with extension :.sql Then put all your queries on the file. Don't forget to add ";" after each instruction. After that, via a command line, execute **mysql < "path-to-your-file/theFilename.sql"**